# Why "iscntrl" returns 2?

Tags: c++

I want to know why, when I print the instruction `iscntrl`, the return value is always 2?

I also want to know why the result of the `isalpha` statement is 1024.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char lettera = 'c';
   char numero = '1';

   isalpha(lettera)? cout << lettera << " è un carattere!" : cout << lettera << " non è un carattere!";
   
   isalpha(numero)? cout << numero << " è un carattere!" : cout << numero << " non è un carattere!";

   cout << endl << isalpha(lettera) << endl; //print 1024
   cout << isalpha(numero) << endl;          //print 0
  
   cout << iscntrl(numero) << endl;  //print 0
   cout << iscntrl(1) << endl;       //print 2
}
```

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions of those functions and what they return? [`isalpha`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/), [`iscntrl`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/iscntrl/). Note that the *particular* non-zero value returned when they aren't returning zero is not defined and could vary by implementation. The key difference is zero vs. non-zero.

Comment: Because they can do this.  **Return non-zero value if the character is a control character, zero otherwise**.

Comment: As to why, the implementation typically has an array indexed by the character value; each element of the array is a set of bits, and the query function applies a bitmask to select the bit or bits that represent the desired result. So, from the description in the question, it looks like `iscntrl(ch)` returns `values[ch] & 0x02`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`iscntrl()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) function return value:

> A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is an alphabetic
> letter. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.

The [`isalpha()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) function return value:

> A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is a control
> character. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.

So, it returns *non-zero* value (not 1) when the condition is `true`. So that's intentional.

Also, a tiny note:

```cpp
isalpha(lettera)? cout << lettera << " è un carattere!" : cout << lettera << " non è un carattere!";
isalpha(numero)? cout << numero << " è un carattere!" : cout << numero << " non è un carattere!";
```

Those two statements are very similar, so you should make a function:

```cpp
inline void printmsg(char ch)
{ 
    std::cout << ch << (isalpha(ch) ? "" : " non") << " è un carattere!"; 
}
```

and call it:

```cpp
printmsg(lettera); 
printmsg(numero);
```

Comment: I would use this instead to reduce further repetition: `void printmsg(char ch) { std::cout << ch << (isalpha(ch) ? "" : " non") << " è un carattere!"; } printmsg(lettera); printmsg(numero);`